# React native connecting to a sql database

Tags: reactjs, database, react-native, react-native-ios

I need someone to point me to the right direction, i am playing around with SQL databases and wish to connect the dots with react native. how do **i get react native user input to update a database value for example.**

if anyone can point me in the right direction please

Answer (score 0):

So typically react native doesnt directly communicate with an sql database, the backend does, this is for many reasons, mainly security. If you want to avoid building a backend, you should look into Firebase. Other than that, you can use SQLLite on react native, but you'll only be able to store locally

To answer your question, you'll probably want to create a simple REST Api backend to communicate with your app. The backend will update the database, not the app.

Comment: Thank you do you have any resources for this? with the use of python

Comment: Google Django or Flask, those are what you'll need with python